# Unidirectional ManyToOne relationship Spring-Boot JPA mapping

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, jpa

Here is my stacktrace:

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.5.RELEASE)

2020-11-23 21:09:19.578  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] pl.umcs.lessonwiz.LessonwizApplication   : Starting LessonwizApplication on DESKTOP-4VPS8T4 with PID 9232 (C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\lessonwiz\build\classes\java\main starte
d by admin in C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\lessonwiz)
2020-11-23 21:09:19.581  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] pl.umcs.lessonwiz.LessonwizApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-11-23 21:09:19.653  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-11-23 21:09:19.653  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-11-23 21:09:20.229  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-11-23 21:09:20.298  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 60ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-11-23 21:09:20.910  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-11-23 21:09:20.921  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-11-23 21:09:20.921  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2020-11-23 21:09:21.016  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-11-23 21:09:21.016  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1363 ms
2020-11-23 21:09:21.058  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-11-23 21:09:21.203  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-11-23 21:09:21.474  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres'
2020-11-23 21:09:21.529  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-11-23 21:09:21.623  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-11-23 21:09:21.672  INFO 9232 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-11-23 21:09:21.713  WARN 9232 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly config
ure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-11-23 21:09:21.738  INFO 9232 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.22.Final
2020-11-23 21:09:21.897  INFO 9232 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-11-23 21:09:21.948  WARN 9232 --- [  restartedMain] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2020-11-23 21:09:22.014  INFO 9232 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2020-11-23 21:09:22.046  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-11-23 21:09:22.047  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositoriesů
2020-11-23 21:09:22.543  WARN 9232 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExce
ption: Error creating bean with name 'courseRepository' defined in pl.umcs.lessonwiz.infrastructure.CourseRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot r
esolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of
 init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property: pl.umcs.lessonwiz.domain.Course.teacherId
2020-11-23 21:09:22.545  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-11-23 21:09:22.545  WARN 9232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allo
wed on a @ManyToOne property: pl.umcs.lessonwiz.domain.Course.teacherId
2020-11-23 21:09:22.545  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-11-23 21:09:22.547  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-11-23 21:09:22.553  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-11-23 21:09:22.582  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-11-23 21:09:22.633  INFO 9232 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-11-23 21:09:22.643 ERROR 9232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'courseRepository' defined in pl.umcs.lessonwiz.infrastructure.CourseRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegi
strar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
 bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property: pl.umcs.lessonwiz.domain.Course.teacherId
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:624) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:612) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at pl.umcs.lessonwiz.LessonwizApplication.main(LessonwizApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allowed o
n a @ManyToOne property: pl.umcs.lessonwiz.domain.Course.teacherId
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property: pl.umcs.lessonwiz.domain.Course.teacherId
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1780) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:973) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:800) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

First entity (with FK):

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "course_id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "course_id_generator", sequenceName = "course_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private LocalTime start;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private LocalTime end;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "day")
    private DayOfWeek day;

    @Column(name = "total_places")
    private int totalPlaces;

    @Column(name = "semester_id")
    private int semesterId;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Teacher.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    @Column(name = "teacher_id")
    private int teacherId;

    public Course(String title, LocalTime start, LocalTime end, DayOfWeek day, int totalPlaces, int semesterId, int teacherId) {
        this.title = title;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.day = day;
        this.totalPlaces = totalPlaces;
        this.semesterId = semesterId;
        this.teacherId = teacherId;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Second entity(without fk):

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "teacher_id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "teacher_id_generator", sequenceName = "teacher_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;

    public Teacher(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
}
```

Part of my DB diagram:
[image: DIAGRAM]

I want to map teacher id with course entity. It is possible to map these entities without collection in 2nd entity? I get these errors only when I add @JoinColumn and @ManyToOne annotations. Thanks for your answers.